# Django, best way to render italics in html for empty text field

Tags: html, django, django-templates, italics

I have a field called `notes` in a model. If the field is empty, I want to output 'No notes' and I want to do it in italics. You can set the text to be 'No Notes' by using a get command in the models.py

```
def get_notes(self):
    if len(self.notes) == 0:
        return "No notes"
    return self.notes
```

How do you have the html render as italics for the text 'No notes'.

Html:

```
<h6>Your Notes: </h6>
    <p>{{ object.get_notes }}</p>
```

Comment: A (form) field, or simply a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## In case you render HTML

In case you render HTML, I would add the "fallback" message to the template only. You can do so with the [**`default`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#default) *template filter*:

```
{{ object.notes | default:"<i>No notes</i>" }}
```

The advantage of this usage is that - in case another template should render another message, or the italics do not fit - you can decide to use something else. Furthermore the template is rather explicit on how the content should be rendered.

Note that we here thus use `.notes`, not a `.get_notes` function that adds some sort of placeholder.

## In case of a *form field*

I would suggest that `"No notes"` is *not* the content of the `CharField`. How would you destinguish `"No notes"` from a user explicitly writing `"No notes"`? What if you later change your mind? Then you have to rewrite all logic in forms, etc. You can however use a `placeholder`, and add relevant markup for that:

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    notes = forms.CharField(
        label='notes', 
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'No notes'})
    )
```

You can then perform markup with a `.css` stylesheet:

```
input::placeholder {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

## Using `get_notes` instead

In case you insist on using `get_notes`, you can first of simplify your function, and furthermore you can use **`mark_safe(..)`** to render *raw* html:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

def get_notes(self):
    return self.notes or mark_safe('<i>No notes</i>')
```

Comment: Thanks for the multiple ways of italicizing the notes; it's very useful to know. I'm going to go with the 'template-only' option.